# Hide div when it's affected with parents 'overflow:hidden;'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on dynamic timeline, parent element is pushing child elements 200px on every click, problem is that, because of design, there is no chance to show only 4 elements on timeline after first click to slider button, my question is, how to hide child element when it "start" to be overflowed with parent, or how to hide elements that are not 100% visible on viewport.

```
// Single timeline element
    $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'timeline-holder ' + value.content_type + '-element' + elementClass,
        'text': 'Text Only',
        'html': '<div class="circle-timeline circle-background-'+ value.override_content_type_icon +'">' +
        // '<p>2005</p>' +
        '<span>' + value.segment_label + '</span>' +
        '<div class="timeline-block">' +
        '<span>' + value.segment_label + '</span>' +
        '<h2>' + value.headline + '<i class="fa fa-star ' + favoriteClass + '" aria-hidden="true"></i>' +
        '<div class="bookmark ' + bookmarkClass + '">B</div>' +
        '</h2>' +
        blockContent +
        imageBlock +
        iframeElement +
        readmoreButton +
        downloadButton +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>'
    }).appendTo('#timeline-slider');
```

I am reading data from json file, here is JS that moves slider when user clicks on it

```
    function moveLeft() {

    var currentMargin = parseInt(tmSlider.css('margin-left'));

    // Check if animation is in progress
    if (!tmSlider.hasClass('animating')) {

        tmSlider.addClass('animating'); // lock slider with class

        elementsToMove = timelineData.timeline.elements_to_move; // reset

        var countElementsLeftToShow = totalElements - stepsPassed - 4;

        sliderLastMove(countElementsLeftToShow);

        stepsPassed = stepsPassed + elementsToMove;

        // Move sldier
        tmSlider.animate({
            'marginLeft': currentMargin - sliderStep
        }, 500, function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                tmSlider.removeClass('animating');
            }, 500);
        });
    }
}

function moveRight() {

    var currentMargin = parseInt(tmSlider.css('margin-left'));

    // Check if animation is in progress
    if (!tmSlider.hasClass('animating')) {

        tmSlider.addClass('animating'); // lock slider with class

        elementsToMove = timelineData.timeline.elements_to_move;

        sliderLastMove(stepsPassed);

        stepsPassed = stepsPassed - elementsToMove;

        // Move slider
        tmSlider.animate({
            'marginLeft': currentMargin + sliderStep
        }, 500, function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                tmSlider.removeClass('animating');
            }, 500);
        });
    }
}

rightArrow.on('click', function () {
    moveLeft();
    prepareData();
    // displayArrow()
});

leftArrow.on('click', function () {
    moveRight();
    // displayArrow();
});
```

Hope this helps, between this is mine 1st question here,

Comment: Checking the actual overflow and how it all rendered just makes the problem more difficult. Can you share the logic that determines what is shown on the timeline? It's probably going to be easier to solve this with logic on the data than with checking DOM and css properties.

Comment: If you're only able to display exactly 4 elements, couldn't you just keep track of the number of elements and do what you need to do when there is more than 4 elements?

Comment: 4 elements are always visible, i am loading content with Ajax, at the and all elements will be loaded but only 4 will be fully visible on view port, 2 divs on sides are half visible

Comment: Does the slider you're using have a method to get the active slide index? So for example if the active slide is slide 3, then you can figure out which elements are out of the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot about this question, but i did this, and it was simple.
I was watching elements `offset().left` until it was equal or more than the `offset().left` of the "move right" arrow, and than oposite of that on the other side.